# What gives you the Super Bonuses in Canyon Capers?

Tags: canyon-capers

In Canyon Capers, you get bonuses once you've completed each level for various things you've accomplished throughout the played level. Gem Bonus and Treasure Bonus are assumedly for how many Gems/Treasure Chests you collected in the level, and the Health and Time Bonuses are probably for depend on how much Health and Time you had left, but what is the Super Bonus for? How do I get multiple of them?

[image: The end level screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breakdown of all points can be found in [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=826860693). The Super Bonus is outlined here, as well:

> Super Bonus - worth 200 pts each - You get 200 points for every enemy you "stun" (kill until they respawn). This does not include the double point bonuses for jumping on two enemies in succession.

Comment: Oh, heh heh, I wrote that. I got tired of waiting for an answer that day and ran a bunch of tests on the first level :P